# Why is the figure not appearing below an itemize in beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics

The figure doesn't appear and there is some weird shifting of the `itemize` environment when the figure should've appeared. Any help on why this is the case?

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Introduction}{Hello}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item stuff
            \item stuff
            \begin{itemize}
                \item stuff\pause, stuff1\pause, stuff2\pause
            \end{itemize}
            \item stuff
            \item stuff
        \end{itemize}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=\textwidth]{whatever.png}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say it's the `\pause` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick-and-dirty solution with and without `overlayarea` usage (however, with 'jumping' content)

The widths and heights of the `overlayarea` environment might be adjusted to the actual values.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}{Hello}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> stuff
  \item<3-> stuff
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<3-> stuff\onslide<4->{, stuff1}\onslide<5->{, stuff2}
    \end{itemize}
  \item<6-> stuff
  \item<7-> stuff
  \end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
  \includegraphics<2->[width=\textwidth]{whatever.png}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{Introduction}{Hello}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> stuff
  \item<3-> stuff
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<3-> stuff\onslide<4->{, stuff1}\onslide<5->{, stuff2}
    \end{itemize}
  \item<6-> stuff
  \item<7-> stuff
  \end{itemize}
  \includegraphics<2->[width=\textwidth]{whatever.png}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, there are other approaches.

Comment: so basically the pause is causing the issues?

Comment: @evan54: I would say, yes. The `\onslide` command is far more powerful (and useful), in my point of view.

Comment: @evan54: I'll come back to it, when I have more time.

Comment: @evan54: Ok, but there might be other solutions as well.

Comment: look forward to it